# dynamic require css with webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, css-loader

let's say this is my server structure:

```
www
  source
    main.js
    assets
      img1
      img2
  siteLink1
     index.html
  siteLink2
     index.html
```

inside both htmls, I have `<script src='../source/bundle.js'/>` so I can have two links with the same JS source .

The problem is that `bundle.js` contains all of the css, which have somehing like :

```
.bg{
  background: url(img1.jpg)
}
```

and then, the webpacked JS added `<style>` that says:

```
.bg{
  background: url(./assets/img1.jpg)
}
```

which is great, if JS and HTML were at the same place, but since they are not, the `style` in html points to the non-existing relative `assets` folder.

So what I really need, is saying to JS - when you put `style` tags with all of css required with `css-loader`, make it relative to the place of the JS, and not to the place of HTML.

What can I do?